# Dependency on a module on a multimodule gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management, multi-module

I have a multi-module project in Gradle.

I refactored the ***common functionality*** into a module named `common`.

I have tests in a different module (lets say `module A`) of the multi-module project that consume the classes under `src/main/java` of the `common` module.

I am able to import these classes from `common` module in test classes of `module A`, but when I run the tests, I get the following error:

> error: package 'common.bla...' does not exist.

This is the `build.gradle` file for `module A` that depends on `common` module for its tests (I have tried all these options):

```
 dependencies  {
     compile project(':common')
     testCompile project(':common')
     testRuntime project(':common')
     runtime project(':common')
     implementation project(":common")
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     testCompileOnly project(':common')
     testRuntimeOnly project(':common')
     testImplementation project(':common')
     runtimeOnly project(':common')
     testCompile project(":common").sourceSets.test.output
     compile project(":common").sourceSets.test.output
     testRuntime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I have also verified that a jar is created in `common/build/libs`.
***What else can I try?***

Comment: could you add some screen how does your project structure look in IDE?

Answer (score 1):

It’s a bit difficult to answer your question with so little context but let me try to do it anyway. From what I understand, you have a directory structure similar to the following (excluding the Gradle Wrapper files):

```
.
├── common
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── common
│                   └── Foobar.java
├── moduleA
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── FoobarTest.java
└── settings.gradle
```

I can successfully run `./gradlew :moduleA:test` (Gradle 5.6.2) from the root directory with the following file contents:

### `./common/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
```

### `./common/src/main/java/common/Foobar.java`

```
package common;

public class Foobar {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.err.println("Foobar");
    }
}
```

### `./moduleA/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation project(':common')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

### `./moduleA/src/test/java/FoobarTest.java`

```
import common.Foobar;

public class FoobarTest {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void myTest() {
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Foobar.class);
    }
}
```

### `./settings.gradle`

```
include 'common', 'moduleA'
```

---

As said, it’s hard to say where exactly your error comes from. If you can’t use my minimal setup to get your own code fixed, then maybe try to update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your non-working setup.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies are convoluted right now. Having both `compile` and `testCompile` and `testCompileOnly` is confusing, if not downright incorrect. `testCompileOnly` may be the reason it’s not working at runtime.

Having `compile` implies runtime and testCompile as well. You can check that using `gradlew common:dependencies`.

I think cleaning up the dependencies will help. If not please check the contents of the jar to contain the expected class.

Comment: Thanks, I did add just the testImplementation dependency but the jar does not contain the required class